# JSoup selector select from right-to-left or left-to-right?

Tags: java, jsoup, sizzle

Does JSoup selector select elements from right-to-left or left-to-right?

Take the 2 as example: `#id .class1` and `#id > .class1`

Comment: You know you can test using online tool @ http://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: This is a great question, upvoted. If Jsoup follows the paradigm of Jquery's Sizzle engine (http://sizzlejs.com/) then it's from right to left. I believe it's from left to right though. I can't check it right now, but you can see the implementation here http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2 , check the parser package. Specifically here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/org/jsoup/parser/TokenQueue.java#TokenQueue

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Documentation on the website, I see:

```
Elements resultLinks = doc.select("h3.r > a"); // direct a after h3
```

It seems like it must work from left to right, so it first selects every `h3` and then it selects those `h3` which have an `a` after them.

Looking at the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/org/jsoup/parser/TokenQueue.java#TokenQueue) seems to confirm this.